# Eclipse RCP app with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, eclipse-rcp

Is MVC achievable in RCP? If so, what frameworks are out there to achieve MVC in an Eclipse RCP app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latest on MVC in RCP can be found in this presentation:

[Eclipse Data Binding - Updating RCP Mail 2.0 Handout](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/6/61/Frank_Gerhardt_Eclipse_Data_Binding.pdf)

The main notions in RCP are:

- Observable
- Bindings

because a RCP application tends to go from MVC to a more flat dependency:

[image: http://img97.i_mageshack.us/img97/2492/mvc1.png]

[image: http://img9.i_mageshack.us/img9/6289/mvc2l.png]